# Neo4j cypher query is not working as expected

Tags: neo4j, cypher, graph-databases

I use the default Movie database `movie-graph` and run a simple query like:

```
MATCH
(:Person{name: 'Tom Hanks'})-[DIRECTED]->(m:Movie)
RETURN m
```

The result should be all movies which Tom Hanks directed which is one `That thing you do`, but it returns 12 movies in which Tom Hanks acted too. why is that?

Answer (score 0):

It's my bad. I forgot to put : in front of DIRECRED and now it's ok.